# Fetching data from html table, when no class name in html

Tags: python

I am getting info in html format, n have to store it. by using beautifulsoup in python i can get the specific info but have to mention the class name in the filter. But am not getting any class name of that table. I want a dict like this : {"Product":"Choclate, Honey, Shampoo", "Quantity":"3, 1, 1", "Price":"45 , 32, 16"}

and the sample html is like this:
Product
Quantity
Price
Choclate
3
₹ 45.00
Honey
2
₹ 32.00
Shampoo
1
₹ 16.00
<table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" width="95%" style="border:0;color:#000000;line-height:150%;text-align:left;font:300 14px/30px &#39;Helvetica Neue&#39;,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif" border=".5px"><thead><tr style="background:#efefef"><th scope="col" width="50%" style="text-align:left;border:1px solid #eee">Product</th>
<th scope="col" width="30%" style="text-align:right;border:1px solid #eee">Quantity</th>
<th scope="col" width="30%" style="text-align:right;border:1px solid #eee">Price</th>
</tr></thead><tbody><tr width="100%"><td width="50%" style="text-align:left;vertical-align:middle;border-left:1px solid #eee;border-bottom:1px solid #eee;border-right:0;border-top:0;word-wrap:break-word">Choclate<br><small></small></td>
<td width="30%" style="text-align:right;vertical-align:middle;border-left:1px solid #eee;border-bottom:1px solid #eee;border-right:0;border-top:0">3</td>
<td width="30%" style="text-align:right;vertical-align:middle;border-left:1px solid #eee;border-bottom:1px solid #eee;border-right:1px solid #eee;border-top:0"><span>₹ 45.00<br><small></small></span></td>
</tr><tr width="100%"><td width="50%" style="text-align:left;vertical-align:middle;border-left:1px solid #eee;border-bottom:1px solid #eee;border-right:0;border-top:0;word-wrap:break-word">Honey<br><small></small></td>
<td width="30%" style="text-align:right;vertical-align:middle;border-left:1px solid #eee;border-bottom:1px solid #eee;border-right:0;border-top:0">2</td>
<td width="30%" style="text-align:right;vertical-align:middle;border-left:1px solid #eee;border-bottom:1px solid #eee;border-right:1px solid #eee;border-top:0"><span>₹ 32.00<br><small></small></span></td>
</tr><tr width="100%"><td width="50%" style="text-align:left;vertical-align:middle;border-left:1px solid #eee;border-bottom:1px solid #eee;border-right:0;border-top:0;word-wrap:break-word">Shampoo<br><small></small></td>
<td width="30%" style="text-align:right;vertical-align:middle;border-left:1px solid #eee;border-bottom:1px solid #eee;border-right:0;border-top:0">1</td>
<td width="30%" style="text-align:right;vertical-align:middle;border-left:1px solid #eee;border-bottom:1px solid #eee;border-right:1px solid #eee;border-top:0"><span>₹ 16.00<br><small></small></span></td>
</tr></tbody><tfoot><tr><td scope="col" style="text-align:left;vertical-align:middle;border-left:0;border-bottom:0;border-right:0;border-top:0;word-wrap:break-word"></td

Answer (score 1):

You don't *have* to give a class name.  If it is the only table simply search for the table tag, else you'll have to look at the surrounding HTML elements and the whole path from the `<body>` element to that table if there are any classes or identifiers or anything else to single out this particular table. If this all fails you may have search for a header cell containing the word *Product* and work your way up to the `<table>` element from there.

As I don't know the surrounding HTML I'll show the fallback solution to search for the header cell with a specific text value:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
from pprint import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main():
    with open('test.html') as html_file:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file)

    header_row_node = soup.find('th', text='Product').parent
    headers = list(header_row_node.stripped_strings)
    header2values = dict((h, list()) for h in headers)
    for row_node in header_row_node.find_parent('table').tbody('tr'):
        product, quantity, price = row_node.stripped_strings
        price = price.split()[-1]  # Just take the number part.
        for header, value in zip(headers, [product, quantity, price]):
            header2values[header].append(value)

    result = dict((h, ', '.join(vs)) for h, vs in header2values.iteritems())
    pprint(result)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For the given test data (which I slightly corrected/completed before saving it as *test.html*) this prints:

```
{u'Price': u'45.00, 32.00, 16.00',
 u'Product': u'Choclate, Honey, Shampoo',
 u'Quantity': u'3, 2, 1'
```